# VisualSVN Hook replace information in file?

Tags: svn, visualsvn, svn-hooks

i will replace automatically informations while SVN-Commitment.

For example:

**myfile.js**

```
/* $Author:User; $ChangeDate:02.01.2014; $Revision:10401; */
function myJavascriptFile(){
}
```

Now when the commitment is runnig the hook should replace the information.

```
$Author:theAuthorname; ...
```

Couldn't find something about that... is this possible with hooks and when 'yes' - how?

thanks for help and happy new year!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hook scripts should never attempt to modify the contents of your transaction. You could:

- Break the commit process entirely
- Find yourself in a race condition
- Slow down everyone while they wait for the hook to complete
- Break the code that the user is attempting to commit (code that compiled for the developer suddenly doesn't compile when checked out)
- (Best-case scenario) what the user *thinks* they just committed isn't what actually went into the repository and they are forced to run `svn update` after every commit just to see what's *really* in the repository.

It's unclear what you're trying to achieve here with this replacement. If `svn:keywords` isn't providing the information or format that you need, don't use it and instead use a different method to achieve your desired state.